# Query about Laplace Eqution and Harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homology-cohomology, harmonic-functions, hodge-theory

In the text below, I am unable to understand how Eq 2.5 represents the **Laplace Equation** because I don't see any partial derivatives etc. Does Eq 2.5 somehow reduce to $\nabla^2 u=0$? The snippet is from [https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/work/psapm.pdf](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/work/psapm.pdf) (pg 4). It would be great if someone could help me understand this form of the Laplace equation.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a generalized version of the Laplace equation where the $A$ and $B$ matrices are playing the role of the partial derivatives. $AB = 0$ is the condition for this "Laplacian" to be separable.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks. Would it possible to expand a little more on your explanation? I am afraid I don't fully comprehend how A and B play the role of partial derivatives.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really have the knowledge to expound further. Hopefully someone else who's more of an expert in this field will chime in.